# For each of the following restrictions, find the smallest size n for strings over $\{a, b, c\}$ that can be used as codes for $27$ people.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For each of the following restrictions, find the smallest size $n$ for strings over $\{a, b, c\}$ that can be used as codes for $27$ people.

a. There are $k$ $a$’s, $l$ $b$’s, and $m$ $c$’s and $k + l + m = n$.

b. Same as Part (a) with the additional restriction that $k = l = m$.

Here, I think the number of strings of length $n$ over $\{a,b,c\}$ that contains $k$ $a$'s, $l$ $b$'s and $m$ $c$'s is $$\frac{n!}{k!  l!  m!}$$ Now I need to solve the inequality that $$\frac{n!}{k! l! m!} \geq 27$$ but I am stuck solving the inequality.

Comment: Observe that $n! \geq 27$ if $n \geq 5$.  Are there particular values of $k$, $l$, and $m$ with $k + l + m = 5$ such that $\frac{5!}{k!l!m!} \geq 27$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $\frac{n!}{k!l!m!}$ is the total number of possible codes.

For question 1, you want $\frac{n!}{k!l!m!}$ > 27. And you also need to satisfy n = k+l+m. And clearly, $\frac{4!}{k!l!m!}$ will not work for all possible k,l,m. We can try n = 5, and see that $\frac{5!}{1!2!2!} = 30 > 27$. Hence, the minimum possible n is 5.

For question 2, we have $\frac{3k!}{k!^{3}}$ > 27. k = 1 does not work obviously. If we try k =2, $\frac{6!}{2!^{3}} = 90 > 27$. Hence, the minimum possible n is 6.

Comment: Thanks very much for such a clear and coherent explanation.